# How to draw absolutely custom shape in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, java-2d, bezier, nurbs

The most complex shape, supported by Java2D API is a Bezier segment. Suppose I want to draw rational segment (each control point has a weight and the entire rendering formula is slightly different).

How to accomplish that?

Is it possible to extend rendering engine to be able to draw more complex shapes?

**UPDATE**

Usual way to implement custom shape is implementing [`Shape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) interface. This interface has key methods to return [`PathIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/PathIterator.html) while `PathIterator` iterates over segment types. There are only 5 segment types. The most curved of them is [`SEG_CUBICTO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/PathIterator.html#SEG_CUBICTO) which is standard Bezier curve with 4 control points (including 2 for beginning and end).

If I apply linear fractional transform to bezier curve, each control point get a weight, as an addition to it's coordinates, and Bezier curve turns to NURBS (not sure about that, have failed to learn exact terminology). Anyway, the formula for curve differs from Bezier.

Comment: I'm not expert on java2d, but based on javadocs, all shapes implements `Shape` interface, so i could say thats way to go if you want something complex and custom made

Comment: Yes, but `Shape` is returning `PathIterator`, while `PathIterator` is returning only fixed number of segment types, the most complex of which is `SEG_CUBICTO` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/PathIterator.html#SEG_CUBICTO

Comment: have a look at this example, maybe this will give you some ideas http://82.157.70.109/mirrorbooks/javaexamples/0596006209_jenut3-chp-12-sect-12.html

Comment: There’s no way around it, your `Shape` implementation has to convert the curve into a sequence of lines, quad, or cubic curves. But given short enough lines there’s no difference to a point by point iteration.

Comment: @Holger theoretically it could be possible to redefine or subclass some underlying rendering classes, like it is doable with Sound API.

Comment: Not really. The rendering is implemented inside non-standard implementation packages. You could hack in modified classes but that would work on that specific single JVM implementation only and is likely to break in the next version. If you have hands on the application doing the rendering you can provide the rendering/rasterization methods to it. But that would have nothing to do with your original question: “implementing the `Shape` interface”.

Comment: No, my original question is not about Shape interface but about drawing in general. I was thinking about something like sound API where, for example, you can add `MP3` functionality by adding some classes on classpath and defining some string correspondences. I was thinking it could be possible to plug custom renderers here too...

Comment: Nothing prevents you from allocating an image buffer and poking in arbitrary pixels!

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill yes, but this will be too complex... I would like to reatin cubic Bezier code and others. Also I would like to stay compatible with AWT based libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really extend the rendering engine: you can create Graphics/Graphics2D subclasses, but you have no control over the instantiation, so you cannot force the drawing framework to pass your subclass to the painting methods.

What you can do is to create a RationalShape implementation of Shape that has methods that draw anything you like, and returns a PathIterator which *approximates* it using Bézier splines. As a user of graphical programs like Photoshop I found that every curve can be approximated very well with Bézier splines, I don't know how complicated the math behind this approximation would be.