# How to create custom shape in java

Tags: java, shapes

I am doing some java games, and I figure it would be cool if the game is made without importing images. Therefore I need to create custom shapes and hand it to Graphics object to draw. The major character in my game will be a dango which is much like a slime, composing from a imperfect circle and two vertical lines as eyes. I should be able to construct dango by given a parameter indicating size. Also, it will be better if I can modify the position of the eyes, or the bottom curve to present the interaction with the floor. Further more, I would be glad if I can fill it with color and give it some texture or something. But all things start from a circle and two lines.

I checked some APIs including `Shape`, `GeneralPath`, `PathIterator`, `Area`, `Ellipse`, and some source code. I learnt how to use GeneralPath to draw straight line, quadratic curve, and bezier curve. But still I don't know how to implement my custom shape. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050086/how-to-draw-absolutely-custom-shape-in-java/20098202#20098202) in stackoverflow but no good answer is posted.

---

In case someone just read the title and skips the content of this question, I shall emphasize that this question is about **create** the custom shape, which means to implement the 'Shape' interface. Not just to **draw** a shape.

Comment: -1, you ought to check the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html) as a **must** before asking question on SO.

Comment: @ambigram_maker 【 I learnt how to use GeneralPath to draw straight line, quadratic curve, and bezier curve. But still I don't know how to implement my custom shape.】 It seems you just read the title of the question and then commented.

Comment: Well... define _implement_. _Where_ do you want to use it? _How_ do you want to implement it?

Comment: @ambigram_maker You may look over the content of the question first, I think the answers are already there.

Comment: Well, we won't write the code for you (on SO that is)... Try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ instead (to get hints).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after a day of research, I finally did it. For anyone who holds the same problem with me, I recommend you to do what I have done.

First, refer to the java api source code, here I chose the source code of [Ellipse2D.class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.java#Ellipse2D). Following the source code, you may ignore the 2 inner static class `Ellipse2D.Double`, `Ellipse2D.Float`, they are not so important at this point.

To implement the `Shape` interface, the most important method is

```
  public PathIterator getPathIterator(AffineTransform at) {
    return new EllipseIterator(this, at);
  }
```

this method is called by paintComponent to get a `PathIterator` to draw. So as what the source code does, you may create your own `ShapeIterator`.

Then the source code of [EllipseIterator](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/awt/geom/EllipseIterator.java#EllipseIterator). As you can see, there are 4 methods (excluding the constructor and the duplicate). You may leave `getWindingRule()` for furthur research. While `isDone()` and `next()` are rather simple to understand.

Then let's focus on `public int currentSegment(float[] args)`.

1. The return values is int, which should be the static final int fields: `SEG_CLOSE`, `SEG_CUBICTO`, etc.. They give instructions on drawing your shape. `SEG_MOVE` will move the start point, `SEG_LINETO` will draw a straight line from start point to end point. There are few more like the quatratic curve and Bezier curve, you may check the details at java api.
2. The argument `float[] args` should also be regarded as return value statement. It delivers the parameters for the instructions above. For `SEG_MOVETO`, `SEG_LINETO`, you need 2 params, so modify args[0] and args[1] ( x and y). For `SEG_QUADTO`, you need 4 params, and `SEG_CUBICTO` needs 6.

Carefully follows the source code, it won't be hard to create a shape. I haven't complete all the methods in Shape interface yet, but the shape can already be drawn by a g2d instance.

Comment: Very interesting. For those who didn't understood well, this description tells way to build shapes in a very low-level, getting entire control on how the shape is built.